# Convert a query from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created this query to filter possible sensible data in MySQL servers, now I have to do the same in SQL Server but I don't have the knowledge to do that.

Query:

```
select table_schema as 'Database', table_name as 'Table', column_name as 'Column', column_type as 'Type' 
from information_schema.columns 
where (column_name like '%cnpj%' or column_name like '%cpf%' or column_name like '%nom%' or column_name like '%fon%' or column_name like '%tel%' or column_name like '%mail%' or column_name like '%end%' or column_name like '%cel%' or column_name like '%gen%' or column_name like '%sex%' or column_name like '%elet%' or column_name like '%doc%' or column_name like '%mae%' or column_name like '%nasc%') 
    and (table_schema not in ('sys', 'information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'mysql'));
```

I've been doing some research to find the equivalent to `information_schema` but no success. (example: `sys.columns`, there's no information about schema or type there).

I'll be very grateful if anyone help me to convert this.

Comment: I think you need to use double quotes or square brackets around the column aliases, not single quotes. Other than that, I think it should be the same.

Comment: @Barmar sounds like they most need help with how to look up schema information, not just query syntax

Comment: @ysth I'm not a sql-server expert, but as far as I can tell from the documentation, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is the same in both databases. So that part of the query doesn't change.

Comment: Only tag the technology you want a solution in... and  specify your actual requirements, i.e. sample data and desired results. That makes it much easier for more people to assist than a "translate this query" type question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has the `Information_Schema.Columns` view, but it has several differences from MySQL:

- It uses "Catalog" for "Schema" (Schema means something else in SQL Server).
- No unified "Column_type". You have to construct it yourself from Data_Type and the Precisions/Scale columns
- *It runs in the context of the currently connected database.* That's a big one: it means you can't use it to look at all databases on the server. `sys.Columns` works the same way. SQL Server does not provide a way to show this for all databases. This was a *deliberate choice* (not an omission), and IMO the **right** choice, since there are security implications involved.

This will get you part of the way there, but again: only for one database at a time:

```
SELECT table_catalog 'Database', table_schema + '.' + table_name 'Table', column_name 'Column'
    , data_type + coalesce( '(' + cast(character_maximum_length as varchar(5))+ ')',
                            '(' + cast(numeric_precision as varchar(3)) + coalesce(',' + cast(nullif(numeric_scale,0) as varchar(3)),'') + ')',
                            '(' + cast(nullif(datetime_precision,case data_type when 'date' then 0 when 'datetime' then 3 end ) as varchar(2)) + ')',
                            '') 'Type'
FROM information_schema.columns c
INNER JOIN (VALUES 
   ('%cnpj%'), ('%cpf%'), ('%nom%'), ('%fon%'), ('%tel%'), ('%mail%'), ('%end%'),
   ('%cel%'),('%gen%'), ('%sex%'), ('%elet%'), ('%doc%'), ('%mae%'), ('%nasc%')
) filter(col) ON c.column_name like filter.col
```

The only option I've found to get around this is making a temp table, putting the query in a varchar variable as an INSERT/SELECT for the temp table with a `USE [?]` at the top, run it repeatedly using [`sp_msforeachdb`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/), then select from the temp table:

```
CREATE Table #ServerColumns (
    [Database] nvarchar(128), 
    [Table] nvarchar(257), 
    [Column] nvarchar(128), 
    [Type] nvarchar(137)
);

DECLARE @query nvarchar(1000) = 
  'IF ''?'' NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'') BEGIN
    USE [?]
    INSERT INTO #ServerColumns 
    SELECT table_catalog ''Database'', table_schema + ''.'' + table_name ''Table'', column_name ''Column''
        , data_type + coalesce( ''('' + cast(character_maximum_length as varchar(5))+ '')'',
                                ''('' + cast(numeric_precision as varchar(3)) + coalesce('','' + cast(nullif(numeric_scale,0) as varchar(3)),'''') + '')'',
                                ''('' + cast(nullif(datetime_precision,case data_type when ''date'' then 0 when ''datetime'' then 3 end ) as varchar(2)) + '')'',
                                '''') ''Type''
    FROM information_schema.columns c
    INNER JOIN (VALUES 
       (''%cnpj%''), (''%cpf%''), (''%nom%''), (''%fon%''), (''%tel%''), (''%mail%''), (''%end%''),
       (''%cel%''),(''%gen%''), (''%sex%''), (''%elet%''), (''%doc%''), (''%mae%''), (''%nasc%'')
    ) filter(col) ON c.column_name like filter.col;
   END'

EXEC sp_msforeachdb @query
SELECT * FROM #ServerColumns
DROP TABLE #ServerColumns
```

This takes advantage of a common pattern on SQL Server for skipping the system databases (`master`, `model`, `msdb`, and `tempdb`), which seemed appropriate to the question.

---

FWIW, this table-value constructor filter technique also works on MySQL. You have to prepend the `ROW` keyword for each entry, but it's still a lot shorter and more scalable than repeating the `LIKE` expression over and over.

Comment: `Information_Schema` is for compatibility only, best to use the `sys` schema

Comment: Came back to this very late. Yes, `sys` is preferred in isolation, but given the whole point of the question is working across two different databases, I felt the slightly-more compatible option was appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of differencies for the query in SQL Server. In SQL Server the information_schema.columns contains info from the current database, not all databases. Secondly, the `column_type` as such does not exists. You need to combine `data_type` and `character_maximum_length`.

```
select table_catalog as 'Database', table_name as 'Table', column_name as 'Column',
 data_type+iif(character_maximum_length is not null, '('+iif(character_maximum_length=-1, 'max', cast(character_maximum_length as varchar(10)))+')', '') as 'Type' 
from information_schema.columns 
where (
     column_name like '%cnpj%' 
  or column_name like '%cpf%' 
  or column_name like '%nom%' 
  or column_name like '%fon%' 
  or column_name like '%tel%' 
  or column_name like '%mail%' 
  or column_name like '%end%' 
  or column_name like '%cel%' 
  or column_name like '%gen%' 
  or column_name like '%sex%' 
  or column_name like '%elet%' 
  or column_name like '%doc%' 
  or column_name like '%mae%' 
  or column_name like '%nasc%'
)
```